# Enabling User to Change Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I'm a little confused with all the layouts options. I want the user to be enable to resize some layouts. How can I do that?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Which layout? What exacly do you wanna know? Stackoverflow is for specific questions. Give us information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to resize panels inside a window, you can use Grid as a panel, and [GridSplitter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(v=vs.110).aspx) as a "draggable edge" so that you can resize other panels inside that main Grid.